# Read program output C++

Tags: c++

I have a TF2 server and if TF2 gets updated while I'm away, server will output:

> Your server is out of date. Please update and restart.

How could I observer/read the output with C++?

The idea is:

```
         1. if (output == "Your server is out of date. Please update and restart.")
         2. kill the application
         3. run update.bat
         4. start observing again
```

Is my idea possible?

[image: this is how server window looks like, just imagine that the last line says: "Your server is out of date. Please update and restart."]

Comment: Does it have to be done with C++?  This seems like the kind of thing that could be more easily accomplished with a shell/batch script.  I'd recommend redirecting your server output to some file at server startup, and then writing a script that reads the file and looks for your update message, and then deletes the file, runs update.bat, and restarts the server if it finds the update message.  You could, of course, do a similar thing in C++ if you want.

Comment: Do you really need to kill the server? Can't you just run update.bat from within the server and continue observing?

Comment: A shell script would sound like a much less painful way of handling this, especially since it allows you trivially to capture the PID of the running process, and you have immediate access to process signalling tools like `kill`.

Comment: @aroth: If I redirect the output to a .txt (via tf2.exe > status.txt) file, I cannot interact with server any more.

Comment: @StevieG: Yes, you must kill, update and run it again.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: If I cannot make it work in c++ I'll try batch.

Comment: @Hami - Why can't you interact with the server anymore?  It should work just the same, you just need to watch the text file instead of the console in order to see the server output.  If you install something like cygwin you can just `tail -f` it, and you'd never know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically a *watchdog*.

A solution can be done using **piping**:

Pipe your server output to standard input from your C++ application (reading it with *cin* will do). For example, if your TF2 server is tf2.exe and your C++ app is cpp.exe:

```
tf2.exe | cpp.exe
```

You will need to execute this command again everytime you're restarting the server (which involves exiting the C++ app after doing so since it will be re-run by the command).

Comment: And how do I do that? I cannot find a simple explanation. Thx

Comment: I don't know what has to be explained further. 
`string input = "";
while (input != "Your server is out of date. Please update and restart.")
{
    cin >> input;
}
run_batch();
exit();`
Btw, as aroth says, C++ is a bad choice for this. A script could do this better (I recommend Bash or Perl).